# Applying a Function to All Text Input Fields

Tags: javascript

I have this bit of code to auto-select the text in an input field.

```
onclick="this.focus();this.select()"
```

And am implementing it like so

```
<input type="text" onclick="this.focus();this.select()" value="xxxxx">
```

I'm thinking it would be cleaner and easier to make updates if I were to apply this code globally instead of inline.

How would I go about adding this code to all text input tags (or maybe to text input tags with a specific ID) from an an external .js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an `<input />` element is automatically focused on clicking that element, you should only need `this.select()`:

```js
$('input[type="text"]').on('click', function () {
  this.select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="something" />
<input type="text" value="something else" />
<input type="text" value="something other" />
```

And, if you wanted to avoid jQuery for this, you could simply:

```js
function selectThis () {
  return this.select();
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'), function (input) {
  input.addEventListener('click', selectThis);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="something" />
<input type="text" value="something else" />
<input type="text" value="something other" />
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`HTMLInputElement.select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement.select).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I went with the jQuery option for consistency in the project. Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

you can make this global for all input of tyoe text by this code

```
$("input[type=text]").click(function(){

$(this).focus();
$(this).select();
 ///do something here
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input:text', function() {
    $(this).select();
});
```